# Find the smallest root of the equation in scilab

Tags: scilab

I need to find the smallest absolute root of the equation with an accuracy of 0.00001 using scilab.
The equation itself: x - cos (1.04 * x) = 0.
Need to build a graph to determine the interval at which the function changes sign. Then calculate the first and second derivatives. It is necessary to determine their sign, which should be the same for all of them ([*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urFzh.png)).

[If1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPAuY.png), then the calculation is performed according to the [following formulas1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQp9Q.png).

[if2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWBKM.png), then the calculation is performed according to the [following formulas2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0unaa.png).

The calculation ends [when](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzgms.png).

How can all this be implemented in scilab?

Ok, so I tried to do this in matlab. But I'm still not sure if everything is composed correctly, and how to transfer this to scilab?

```
clc;
clear;

syms x
f = x - cos(1.04*x);
a=0.5;
b=1;
eps=0.00001;
i=0;
c=(a+b)/2;
f1=diff(f);
f2=diff(f1);
while(abs(b-a)>eps)
    if((subs(f1,x,c)*subs(f2,x,c))>=0)
        a=a-(b-a)*subs(f,x,a)/(subs(f,x,b)-subs(f,x,a));
        b=b-subs(f,x,b)/subs(f1,x,b);
    else
        a=a-subs(f,x,a)/subs(f1,x,a);
        b=b-(b-a)*subs(f,x,b)/(subs(f,x,b)-subs(f,x,a));
    end
    i=i+1;
end
fprintf('b=% f \n', double(b))
ezplot(f,[0.5 1]),hold on
plot(b,subs(f,x,b),'or')
grid on
```

Here is what I have in scilab.

```
clc;
clear;
a=0.5;
b=1;
deff ("y = f (x)", "y = x-cos (1.04 * x)")
deff ("y = f1(x)", "y = 1.04.*sin(1.04*x)+1")
deff ("y = f2(x)", "y = 1.0816.*cos(1.04*x)")
eps=0.00001;
i=0;
c=(a+b)/2;
m=0;
com1 = ["k                 a                 b                 absolute          f(a)               f(b)              f1(b)"];
tab = [];
while(abs(b-a)>eps)
    if((f1(c)*f2(c))>=0)
        a=a-(b-a)*f(a)/(f(b)-f(a));
        b=b-f(b)/f1(b);
    else
        a=a-f(a)/f1(a);
        b=b-(b-a)*f(b)/(f(b)-f(a));
    end
    i=i+1;
    m=abs(b-a);
    tab = [tab; i a b m f(a) f(b) f1(b)];
end
disp('b=', double(b))
disp(tab)
fprintfMat("table.txt", tab, "%1.15f", com1)
fplot2d(-10:0.1:10,f)
plot(b,f(b),'or')
xgrid
```

Comment: What is the same of this method ? Seems to construct successive intervals bounded  by Newton and Secant iterates...

Comment: Perhaps the method I proposed is incorrect. I just don't know how to implement this in scilab.

Comment: If you just need to find a root just use the built-in `fsolve()` function.

Comment: Ok, I tried using the fsolve () function, but then my teacher said that I should use the original method that I described in the question.

Comment: Do you have skills in programming ? Implementing your method will look rather the same in C, Pascal, Python and Scilab.

Comment: It's more a question of my knowledge of mathematics. If only I understood, I could easily do it in C++.

Comment: Well, if you know a bit of algorithmic and know derivatives of functions where is the difficulty here ?

Comment: Please check what I did in matlab. Is this correct? How do I transfer this to scilab?

Comment: You can't, Scilab does not have symbolic capabilities, hence you have to compute derivatives by hand. The rest of the code should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: no. it doesn't work. Undefined variable syms error

Comment: That's what I said before (please completely read answers): Scilab does not have symbolic capabilities. You have to compute the derivatives by hand, not a big deal...

Comment: Ok, now the only thing I don’t understand is how to implement "subs" in scilab

Comment: You have to compute the first and second derivative *by hand* and replace the subs call by the evaluation of these,

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: You have to use Scilab functions (like C functions, but Scilab), e.g. defined in the short way `deff("y=f(x)","y=x-cos(1.04*x)")`. Then you can evaluate e.g. `f(a)` if `a` is defined before.

Comment: Yep. Now it works. But the schedule is not being built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent command of Matlab `ezplot` does not exist but a close one is `fplot2d`. To add a grid you have `xgrid`.

```
    clc;
    clear;
    a=0.5;
    b=1;
    deff ("y = f (x)", "y = x-cos (1.04 * x)")
    deff ("y = f1(x)", "y = 1.04.*sin(1.04*x)+1")
    deff ("y = f2(x)", "y = 1.0816.*cos(1.04*x)")
    eps=0.00001;
    i=0;
    c=(a+b)/2;
    
    tab = [a,b];
    while(abs(b-a)>eps)
        if((f1(c)*f2(c))>=0)
            a=a-(b-a)*f(a)/(f(b)-f(a));
            b=b-f(b)/f1(b);
        else
            a=a-f(a)/f1(a);
            b=b-(b-a)*f(b)/(f(b)-f(a));
        end
        tab = [tab; a b];
        i=i+1;
    end
    disp('b=% f \n', double(b))
    disp(tab)
    fprintfMat("table.txt",tab)
    fplot2d(-10:0.1:10,f)
    plot(b,f(b),'or')
    xgrid
```

The image has been exported from Scilab with `xs2png(0,"graph.png") :
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make intermediate calculations appear in the table as a text file?

Comment: Do you mean successive a and b values ?

Comment: Yes. Their values should be entered in a table in a text file.

Comment: I have added the construction of the table, display and output in a text file. You should be able to modify de script as needed now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything turned out, I even modified your script. Added headers to the first line. And even removed the output of the first variables, since it is not necessary.